# Special char encoding

Tags: utf-8, linkedin-api

LinkedIn isn't encoding special chars when using their share API. Specifically having issues with quotations. Facebook Sharer seems to work fine but the LinkedIn one chokes when using ampersand encoding. The below renders as "We have a drone, and we&#8217;re prepared to shoot" and not as the intended "We have a drone, and we’re prepared to shoot".

```
<meta property="og:title" content="We have a drone, and we&#8217;re prepared to shoot" />
```

Site in question: http://nubix.ca/blog/we-have-a-drone-and-were-prepared-to-shoot/

Answer (score 1):

`&#8217;` is an HTML character reference.  That is the correct thing to use inside of a `<meta property>` tag, as that is part of the HTML itself.

For the "Share this article" buttons at the button of the page, the Twitter and Linkedin share URLs are not encoded correctly.  They both have the page title encoded as this:

```
We%20have%20a%20drone%2C%20and%20we%26%238217%3Bre%20prepared%20to%20shoot
```

Which is wrong, it needs to be encoded as this instead:

```
We%20have%20a%20drone%2C%20and%20we%E2%80%99re%20prepared%20to%20shoot
```

`%26%238217%3B` is the url-encoded form of the literal string `&#8217;`, which gets displayed as-is because HTML character references have no meaning in URLs.

`%E2%80%99` is the url-encoded form of the raw UTF-8 encoded octets of the Unicode `’` character.

So, whoever is generating the share URLs for Twitter and LinkedIn is not decoding the HTML character reference `&#8217;` to its actual Unicode codepoint `U+2019` and then encoding it as UTF-8 octets `E2 80 99` in the share URLs.  Or more likely, is just outputting the same `&#8217;` text as-is in both HTML and URLs without taking into account that they encode Unicode characters in semantically different ways.

The Email and Facebook share URLs do not suffer from this problem because they are not specifying the page title anywhere.  Facebook in particular is being passed just the page URL, and then it retrieves the page's HTML metadata, where `&#8217;` has meaning and gets properly decoded as `’`.